# Java's FlowLayout does not resize correctly

Tags: java, swing, layout

I created a `JFrame` initialized with a `BorderLayout` and a `JScrollPane` as its `CENTER` element.

The scroll pane is set with `VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS` and `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` policies.  The intent of my `frame` is to have a controlled width, while the height should grow/shrink as data is added/removed.

Inside my `scroll pane`, I added a simple `JPanel` (lets call it the content panel) which is initialized with a `FlowLayout` (and `LEADING` policy).

In order to test this, I simply populate my `content panel` with 20 `JLabel("Item " + n)` components where `n` is the loop counter.

I would expect to see my `labels` shown on a single row if the `frame` is large enough and the labels wrap to other lines when I shrink the width.  But instead, there is only a single line displayed with no wrapping... ever.

Does anyone know why the `flow layout` does not wrap when a `scroll pane` is involved?

If I remove the `scroll pane` all together and put the `content panel` directly in the `frame`, the desired wrapping effect occurs, but if the `frame` height is shrunk smaller than the `content panel` height it just disappears.

The idea is that I want my `labels` to be wrapped when necessary but also always be visible if it means having to scroll up/down.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Wrap Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/06/wrap-layout/) gives an explanation and a solution.

Comment: It seems to work exactly as needed/expected so far!  Let's hope that Oracle invests more into Swing than Sun was willing to!  Thanks a lot camickr!

Comment: Would you say that the FlowLayout has bugs or do you think it was Sun' intent for it to behave this way?  The WrapLayout makes so much more sense it should be part of Swing!

Comment: Its not a bug because there is no code that attempts to dynamically recalculate the preferred size. Its just the way someone designed it to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you work with the designer, you have to set the `prefferedSize` property to null (delete what is set) then set the preferred size by clicking the triple dots [...] button next to the `prefferedsize` property name and put your preferred value.

I encountered the same problem and it works for me.